# Programa en Python para verificar cubo Rubik

Tags: python

Estoy haciendo un código para verificar si se hicieron los movimientos correctos en un Rubik 2D.
Por ejemplo:

```
matriz = [[1,2,3],
      [1,2,3],
      [1,2,3]]
```

Para mover la fila1 a la izquierda y la columna2 hacia abajo.
Solo he intentado este pedazo de código para mover las filas.

```
[g[-1]] + g[:-1])
```

**¿Cómo se podría mover las filas a la izquierda o derecha y las columnas hacia arriba o abajo en la matriz?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando te veas atorado, define una función que haga lo que necesitas. Al principio estará vacía, pero así podrás concentrarte en un problema a la vez.

Las operaciones de intercambio en Python se simplifican usando la asignación múltiple. Si tienes dos variables, `a` y `b`, y deseas intercambiar sus valores, puedes hacerlo en una sola operación:

```
a, b = b, a
```

Así es simple intercambiar filas, como en esta función que intercambia las filas `i` y `j` de una matriz:

```
def intercambiar_filas(matriz, i, j):
    matriz[i], matriz[j] = matriz[j], matriz[i]
    return matriz
```

El intercambio de columnas sigue el mismo principio, pero es un poco más largo, ya que hay que intercambiar celda por celda:

```
def intercambiar_columnas(matriz, i, j):
    for fila in range(len(matriz)):
        matriz[fila][i], matriz[fila][j] = matriz[fila][j], matriz[fila][i]
    return matriz
```

**Comprobación**

```
def imprimir_matriz(matriz, titulo):
    print(titulo)
    for fila in matriz:
        for valor in fila:
            print(valor, end=" ")
        print()
    print()

matriz = [[1,2,3],
      [3,4,5],
      [6,7,8]]

imprimir_matriz(matriz, "original")
matriz = intercambiar_filas(matriz, 0, 2)
imprimir_matriz(matriz, "intercambiar filas 0 y 2")
matriz = intercambiar_columnas(matriz, 0, 1)
imprimir_matriz(matriz, "intercambiar columnas 0 y 1")
```

produce:

```
original
1 2 3 
3 4 5 
6 7 8 

intercambiar filas 0 y 2
6 7 8 
3 4 5 
1 2 3 

intercambiar columnas 0 y 1
7 6 8 
4 3 5 
2 1 3
```